How to create a shared set of custom color names in flutter?
I'm using Flutter 3.22 and I have started, for the first time in years, to create my personal library of reusable widgets and utilities.
Everything is going well, except for a thing that I'm not getting how to do.
Basically what I want to do is creating a custom set of color names that I can recall within the widgets around the library and the final applications. Something like:
Container(
   color: Theme.of(context).myCustomColorName
)

this by defining myCustomColorName somewhere around (don't know where!). I'm not getting how to do this, because I found that I can do in the main.dart of every app
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      ...
    ),
  )
)

but the properties are fixed, I cannot really define my custom colors.
Until now I've always used a class with static properties to define colors, like
class AppColors {
  static const Color primaryColor = Color(0xFF3DB4F5);
  ...
}

but this is not "portable", since it's not something that can be replicated around.
I'm stuck, any suggestion?

see ThemeData.extensions and ThemeData.extension

checkout this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen, search for "color". They use an .xml file to store all kinds of color. Is this appropriate for your situation?

As a simple workaround (in addition to dealing with extensions property can achieve it by creating a custom extension to the ThemeData and using it across your app.
Example of creating the extension:
extension CustomAppThemeData on ThemeData {
  Color get customPrimaryColor => const Color(0xFF3DB4F5);
}

Next, make sure that there is an applied theme across the app. For instance, set the theme for the MaterialApp that is used in the app's main widget:
void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(),
    );
  }
}

Since the CustomAppThemeData is an extension of ThemeData, you could access primaryColor as Theme.of(context).primaryColor (because your main app widget has a theme). Example:
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Colors Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          // Here
          color: Theme.of(context).customPrimaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


 Tip:
If you keep the name of the color declared in the extension as primaryColor, you might get a different color! ThemeData has a property called primaryColor, which will be the accessible one instead of your custom color.
So, what you could do is change the name of your custom color (such as mentioned in the code example customPrimaryColor), or consider the default primaryColor of the ThemeData:
ThemeData(primaryColor: const Color(0xFF3DB4F5)),

// Use it as:
Theme.of(context).primaryColor

therefore there is no need to declare a custom color.

no need for "a custom extension" - ThemeData is already designed to be extended, it has something that is called extensions and extension

@pskink Although I agree that ThemeExtension is a viable way to extend the theme functionality, creating a custom extension of ThemeData is not always a bad idea. In my opinion, the advantage of it is the simplicity, a direct way to add a few custom properties. However, ThemeExtension can be added to the answer, as a scalable, type-safe, and cleaner approach, Thank you for your feedback.

Theme widget is used for providing some properties to descendant widgets - your solution creates a static customPrimaryColor that cannot be defined per Theme scope - you cannot create a red customPrimaryColor for the whole app and green customPrimaryColor (or yellow or whatever color) for some other particular screens (or even parts of screens) - it does not differ from class AppColors { that was posted by OP - i mean Theme.of(context).primaryColor is exactly the same as AppColors.primaryColor
